# For each row check if value in one column exists in two other columns

Tags: r, dplyr

Assume we have the following `data frame`:

```
df <- data.frame(X1 = 1:5, X2 = 6:10, X3 = c(6, 2, 3, 0, 2))

  X1 X2 X3
1  1  6  6
2  2  7  2
3  3  8  3
4  4  9  0
5  5 10  2
```

I would like to add a new column (`X4`) made of logical values. For each row: if `X3` is equal to `X1` or `X2`, then `X4` should be `TRUE`, otherwise `FALSE`.

I tried:

```
mutate(df, X4 = X3 %in% c(X2, X1))

  X1 X2 X3    X4
1  1  6  6  TRUE # OK
2  2  7  2  TRUE # OK
3  3  8  3  TRUE # OK
4  4  9  0 FALSE # OK
5  5 10  2  TRUE # expected to be FALSE
```

Most importantly, my real `df` is *very* large, so I would like to **avoid using `for-loops`**. I would privilege the shortest (less amount of code) and fastest solution.

Comment: I think you need `mutate(df, X4 = X3 == X1 | X3 == X2)`. `c(X2, X1)` will concatenate columns X1 and X2 and thus you are checking if element from X3 is from `X1` and `X2` combined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Reduce`

```
Reduce(`|`, lapply(df[1:2], `==`, df[,3]))
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

#### Benchmarking

On a bigger data makes more sense

```
library(microbenchmark)
set.seed(24)
df <- data.frame(X1= sample(1:5, 1e6, replace=TRUE), X2 = sample(1:10, 1e6, replace=TRUE),
       X3 = sample(1:10, 1e6, replace=TRUE))

f2 <- function(df) Reduce(`|`, lapply(df[1:2], `==`, df[,3]))
f3 <- function(df) with(df, X3==X1 | X3==X2)
microbenchmark(f1(df), f2(df), f3(df))
#Unit: milliseconds
#   expr         min         lq       mean     median         uq      max neval

# f2(df)    8.191218   10.83333   23.28081   16.42744   22.26866  143.025   100
# f3(df)    8.154506   10.58878   19.17879   11.49179   22.41255  144.510   100
```

The `apply` is slower as I thought, but the `Reduce` is not as slow..

Comment: *anyDuplicated* wouldn't work for `df1 <- data.frame(X1 = 1:3, X2 = c(1, 1, 2), X3 = 9)` ?

Comment: @zx8754  Yes, you are right.  The idea was based on the position

Comment: Found your post after answering [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48336563/filtering-rows-in-a-dataset-by-columns-using-r), maybe just remove anyDuplicated option? Reduce still works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this vectorized which is provably the fastest:

```
df$X4 <- with(df, X3==X1 | X3==X2)
```

---

**benchmarking**

```
library(microbenchmark)
df <- data.frame(X1 = 1:5, X2 = 6:10, X3 = c(6, 2, 3, 0, 2))

f1 <- function(df) apply(df[1:3], 1, FUN = anyDuplicated)>0
f2 <- function(df) Reduce(`|`, lapply(df[1:2], `==`, df[,3]))
f3 <- function(df) with(df, X3==X1 | X3==X2)

all(f1(df)==f2(df))
#[1] TRUE
all(f1(df)==f3(df))
#[1] TRUE

res <- microbenchmark(f1(df), f2(df), f3(df))

print(res, order="mean")

# Unit: microseconds
   # expr     min       lq      mean  median      uq     max neval
 # f3(df)  14.115  15.3980  17.57113  17.537  17.965  40.634   100
 # f2(df)  79.130  80.8405  86.41780  85.118  88.325 124.468   100
 # f1(df) 223.273 225.6255 235.95907 228.619 238.243 497.445   100
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution using [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr).

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(X4 = any(c(X1, X2) %in% X3)) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 5 x 4
#      X1    X2    X3 X4   
#   <int> <int> <dbl> <lgl>
# 1     1     6  6.00 T    
# 2     2     7  2.00 T    
# 3     3     8  3.00 T    
# 4     4     9  0    F    
# 5     5    10  2.00 F
```