# Filtering rows in a dataset by columns

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have the following table:

```
FN LN LN1 LN2 LN3 LN4 LN5
a   b   b   x   x   x   x
a   c   b   d   e   NA  NA
a   d   c   a   b   x   x
a   e   b   c   d   x   e
```

I'm filtering records for which LN is present in LN1 to LN5.

The code I used:

```
testFilter = filter(test, LN %in% c(LN1, LN2, LN3, LN4, LN5))
```

The result is not what I expect:

```
ï..FN LN LN1 LN2 LN3  LN4  LN5
1     a  b   b   x   x    x    x
2     a  c   b   d   e <NA> <NA>
3     a  d   c   a   b    x    x
4     a  e   b   c   d    x    e
```

I understand that `c(LN1, LN2, LN3, LN4, LN5)` gives: `"b" "b" "c" "b" "x" "d" "a" "c" "x" "e" "b" "d" "x" NA  "x" "x" "x" NA  "x" "e"` and know this is where the mistake is.

Ideally, I want to return only the 1st and 4th record.

```
FN LN LN1 LN2 LN3 LN4 LN5
a   b   b   x   x   x   x
a   e   b   c   d   x   e
```

I want to filter them only using column names. This is just a subset of 5.4M records.

Comment: I guess you mean `subset` not `filter` (which is for time series). `LN` is a column name, as `LN1` to `LN5` so your "condition" cannot work. What exactly do you want to do ?

Comment: I want to display the records which have the value of LN present in their corresponding LN1 or LN2 or LN3 or LN4 or LN5. Thanks for the quick response!
In the 1st record, 'b' is present in LN1. So, display the 1st record.
In the 2nd record, 'c' is not present in LN1/LN2/3/4/5. So, don't display it.
In the 3rd record, 'd' is not present in LN1/LN2/3/4/5. So, don't display it.
In the 4th record, 'e' is present in LN5. So, display it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using *apply*:

```
# data
df1 <- read.table(text = "
FN LN LN1 LN2 LN3 LN4 LN5
a   b   b   x   x   x   x
a   c   b   d   e   NA  NA
a   d   c   a   b   x   x
a   e   b   c   d   x   e", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


df1[ apply(df1, 1, function(i) i[2] %in% i[3:7]), ]
#   FN LN LN1 LN2 LN3 LN4 LN5
# 1  a  b   b   x   x   x   x
# 4  a  e   b   c   d   x   e
```

---

**Note:** Consider using other solutions below for big datasets, which can be **60** times faster than this *apply* solution.

Comment: ha ha, why not use the fastest solution?

Comment: @EricFail Hmm, why "ha ha"? I added note after getting many upvotes, and wanted to highlight for others data.table solution.

Comment: I was laughing at myself for asking sine it's my somewhat clunky code that is _the fastest solution_.

Answer (score 8):

There is an alternative approach using `data.table` and `Reduce()`:

```
library(data.table)
cols <- paste0("LN", 1:5)
setDT(test)[test[, .I[Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, function(x) !is.na(x) & LN == x))], 
                 .SDcols = cols]]
```

> ```
>    FN LN LN1 LN2 LN3 LN4 LN5
> 1:  a  b   b   x   x   x   x
> 2:  a  e   b   c   d   x   e
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
test <- fread(
"FN LN LN1 LN2 LN3 LN4 LN5
  a   b   b   x   x   x   x
  a   c   b   d   e   NA  NA
  a   d   c   a   b   x   x
  a   e   b   c   d   x   e")
```

#### Benchmark

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
n_row <- 1e6L
set.seed(123L)
DT <- data.table(
  FN = "a",
  LN = sample(letters, n_row, TRUE))
cols <- paste0("LN", 1:5)
DT[, (cols) := lapply(1:5, function(x) sample(c(letters, NA), n_row, TRUE))]
DT
df1 <- as.data.frame(DT)

bm <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  zx8754 = {
    df1[ apply(df1, 1, function(i) i[2] %in% i[3:7]), ]
  },
  eric = {
    df1[ which(df1$LN == df1$LN1 |
                 df1$LN == df1$LN2 |
                 df1$LN == df1$LN3 |
                 df1$LN == df1$LN4 |
                 df1$LN == df1$LN5), ]
  },
  uwe = {
    DT[DT[, .I[Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, function(x) !is.na(x) & LN == x))], 
          .SDcols = cols]]
  },
  axe = { 
    filter_at(df1, vars(num_range("LN", 1:5)), any_vars(. == LN))
  },
  jaap = {df1[!!rowSums(df1$LN == df1[, 3:7], na.rm = TRUE),]},
  times = 50L
)
print(bm, "ms")
```

> ```
> Unit: milliseconds
>    expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval cld
>  zx8754 3120.68925 3330.12289 3508.03001 3460.83459 3589.10255 4552.9070    50   c
>    eric   69.74435   79.11995  101.80188   83.78996   98.24054  309.3864    50 a  
>     uwe   93.26621  115.30266  130.91483  121.64281  131.75704  292.8094    50 a  
>     axe   69.82137   79.54149   96.70102   81.98631   95.77107  315.3111    50 a  
>    jaap  362.39318  489.86989  543.39510  544.13079  570.10874 1110.1317    50  b
> ```

For 1 M rows, the hard coded subsetting is the fastest, followed by the `data.table`/`Reduce()` and `dplyr`/`filter_at` approaches.  Using `apply()` is 60 times slower.

```
ggplot(bm, aes(expr, time)) + geom_violin() + scale_y_log10() + stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_boot)
```

[image]

Comment: Really educational answer! Also great with the benchmark comparing the different answers.

Answer (score 8):

A quick and very easy `dplyr` solution:

```
filter_at(df1, vars(num_range("LN", 1:5)), any_vars(. == LN))
```

This is very similar in performance as the hard coded answer by @EricFail, because this simply internally extends the call to:

```
filter(df1, (LN1 == LN) | (LN2 == LN) | (LN3 == LN) | (LN4 == LN) | (LN5 == LN))
```

Instead of `num_range` any other `select` helpers can be used within `vars` to easily select many variables based on their names. Or one can directly give column positions.

Answer (score 6):

not the simplest code, but

```
df1[ which(df1$LN == df1$LN1 |
           df1$LN == df1$LN2 |
           df1$LN == df1$LN3 |
           df1$LN == df1$LN4 |
           df1$LN == df1$LN5), ]
#>   FN LN LN1 LN2 LN3 LN4 LN5
#> 1  a  b   b   x   x   x   x
#> 4  a  e   b   c   d   x   e
```

Comment: I would prefer this solution, but it doesn't scale well, imagine we have 100 columns.

Comment: If they are named in some logical way this could probable be rewritten.

Answer (score 5):

You could also use `rowSums`:

```
df1[!!rowSums(df1$LN == df1[, 3:7], na.rm = TRUE),]
```

which gives:

> ```
>   FN LN LN1 LN2 LN3 LN4 LN5
> 1  a  b   b   x   x   x   x
> 4  a  e   b   c   d   x   e
> ```

For a benchmark, see the [answer of @Uwe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48337549/2204410).