# simplify call to use multiple logical criteria on one variable inside which function while only calling the variables once

Tags: r, optimization

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48337321/1305688) I am trying to simplify a `which` call to avoid calling the data-frame, here `mtcars`, and the variable I am conditioning on, here `cyl`, more then once.

Say this is my code,

```
mtcars[with(mtcars, which(cyl == gear | cyl == carb)), ]
```

Here I am calling the data-frame twice and the variable  `cyl` is also called twice. I imagine there's some simple way to write something a long the line of `cyl %in% c(carb, gear)` or something like it.

The main idea is that I am looking for a way to only state `mtcars`, `cyl`, `gear`, and `carb` once in my call.

I realize this is pretty simple, but it's only to illustrate the issue. Take a look at the question linked above if you feel like studying a more elaborate example.

Comment: `subset(mtcars, cyl == gear | cyl == carb)` would also be shorter and for a more elaborate example: `mtcars[rowSums(mtcars[cols] == mtcars$cyl) > 0, ]` where `cols` contains the columns of interest

Comment: why are you asking this question? It looks like you got really good answers in previous question... use them

Comment: @minem It wasn't my question. I wrote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48337321/1305688) which I think is kinda clunky, in it's repetitiveness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% mutate(rownames = rownames(.)) %>% filter(cyl == gear | cyl == carb)

    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb       rownames
1  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1     Datsun 710
2  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2      Merc 240D
3  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2       Merc 230
4  32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1       Fiat 128
5  30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2    Honda Civic
6  33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1 Toyota Corolla
7  27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1      Fiat X1-9
8  19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6   Ferrari Dino
9  15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8  Maserati Bora
10 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2     Volvo 142E
```

---

If you don't need the rownames:

```
mtcars %>% filter(cyl == gear | cyl == carb)

    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
2  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
3  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
4  32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
5  30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
6  33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
7  27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
8  19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
9  15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
10 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
```

But I don't think there's a way to simplify `(cyl == gear | cyl == carb)` so it only calls cyl once.

Answer (score 1):

look at `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
as.data.table(mtcars, keep.rownames = T)[cyl == gear | cyl == carb,]
#                 rn  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#  1:     Datsun 710 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#  2:      Merc 240D 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#  3:       Merc 230 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#  4:       Fiat 128 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#  5:    Honda Civic 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#  6: Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#  7:      Fiat X1-9 27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
#  8:   Ferrari Dino 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
#  9:  Maserati Bora 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
# 10:     Volvo 142E 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider base R by stacking every filter with `do.call(rbind, ...)`:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(c("gear", "carb"), function(s) subset(mtcars, cyl == mtcars[s])))

#                 mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Datsun 710     22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Merc 240D      24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
# Merc 230       22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
# Fiat 128       32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
# Honda Civic    30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
# Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
# Fiat X1-9      27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
# Volvo 142E     21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
# Ferrari Dino   19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
# Maserati Bora  15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
```